# Popup in UIImagePicker Not rotating

Tags: ios, uipickerview

Is it possible to rotate ImagePicker Popup in Landscape mode in iPhone?

```
if([self.ysImagePicker isPopoverVisible])
{
    [self.ysImagePicker dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    self.ysImagePicker = nil;
}
else
{
    //  UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] init];

    self.ysImagePicker = [[YSImagePickerEditor alloc] init];
    self.ysImagePicker.delegate = self;

    [self.ysImagePicker presentImagePickerPopoverOverButtonLibrary:barBtn withSize:CGSizeMake(745, 500)];
}
```

Comment: when you are rotating device then you want to rotate that ?

Comment: app is in landscap mode i have to select Image from library,but UIimagePicker returning Popup in portrait mode.

Comment: Give some more details about your qus,confusion rotating device or ImagePiker popup

Comment: Application is not showing pop of UIimagePicker in landscape mode. Is it so?

Comment: No,not on device rotation,orientation is only landscape,

Comment: what is YSImagePickerEditor?

Comment: Show some more code. I ll help u

Comment: YSImagePickerEditor is library for uiimagepicker.wait...

Comment: if i use only uiimage picker(without YSImagePickerEditor) the my code will be   picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            }
            picker.delegate = self;
            picker.allowsEditing = YES;
            if( [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront] || [UIImagePickerController isCameraDeviceAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceRear])
          
                picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
            
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UIImagePickerController class not supports ladscape mode. you have to use assetslibrary for landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at [this documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html):

**The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the [cameraOverlayView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/cameraOverlayView) property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.**

But you can create your own image picker by using the AssetsLibrary framework to access the list of images.